# MSBUILD : error MSB1008: Only one project can be specified while make setup file

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, kmdf

I got this error while trying to build a setup of driver project

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0>msbuild /t:clean /t:build C:\Users\iomadmin\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\KMDF\KMDF Driver5\KMDF Driver5.sln /p:Configuration="Debug" /p:Platform=Win32 /p:TargetVersion="Windows10" /p:TargetPlatformVersion="10.0.10010.0"
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 14.0.25420.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

MSBUILD : error MSB1008: Only one project can be specified.
Switch: Studio

For switch syntax, type "MSBuild /help"
```

Any idea about this error?? how solve this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the path to your file in quotation marks (`"`) to indicate the path is one argument. Since the path contains spaces (between `Visual` and `Studio`), the `Studio` part is considered a new argument and MSBuild doesn't know what to do with it:

```
msbuild /t:clean /t:build "C:\Users\iomadmin\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\KMDF\KMDF Driver5\KMDF Driver5.sln" /p:Configuration="Debug" /p:Platform=Win32 /p:TargetVersion="Windows10" /p:TargetPlatformVersion="10.0.10010.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void GetExeFile(string link)
{
        Process compiler = new Process();
        compiler.StartInfo.FileName =@"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe";
        compiler.StartInfo.Arguments = link + @"‪C:\Users\khan\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Calculator\Calculator.sln /t:build /r:System.dll /out:sample.exe stdstr.cs";
        compiler.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        compiler.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        compiler.Start();
        txtGetContent.Text = compiler.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        compiler.WaitForExit();
}
```